# Change of variables w/jacobian

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, substitution, multiple-integral

$$ \iiint z \, dV $$

over region D. D is bounded by by the paraboloid $z=4-x^2-4y^2 $ and
the $xy$-plane. Use $x=2u\cos v ,y=u\sin v,z=w$

I found the Jacobian $J(u,v,w)=2u $.

I substituted $x=2u\cos v ,y=u\sin v,z=w$ in $z=4-x^2-4y^2 $ and got $$z=4-4u^2 $$

I understand that z axis' lower limit is 0 (because of the xy plane) and  $z=4-4u^2 $. Other than that, I have no idea how I can get the limits of  $du$ and $dv$. I'd appreciate if someone shows me step by step how we can get those limits because I'm really confused at this point.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\iiint_{\mrm{D}}z\,\dd^{3}\vec{r} & =
\int_{0}^{4}z\iint_{x^{2}\ +\ 4y^{2}\ <\ 4\ -\ z} \,\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z =
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{4}z\iint_{x^{2}\ +\ y^{2}\ <\ 4\ -\ z}
\,\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{4}z\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\root{4 - z}}\rho
\,\dd\rho\,\dd\phi\,\dd z =
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{4}z\bracks{2\pi\,{\pars{\root{4 - z}}^{2} \over 2}}\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\,\pi\int_{0}^{4}\pars{4z - z^{2}}\,\dd z =
\bbox[10px,#ffe,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{{16 \over 3}\,\pi}} \approx 16.7552
\end{align}